# Short stutter after animation finishes

Tags: html, css

I made a glow and padding extension effect when hovering over link elements usign CSS3. However when the animation finishes, and you continue hovering over it, there's a short stutter and the padding extends a bit more.

The CSS:

```
#links {
    background: rgba(34,34,34,0.75);
    max-width: 400px;
    padding: 0px 10px 2px 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    right: -100px;
    bottom: -100px;
    clear: both;
    z-index: -1;
}

#links h3 {
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: whitesmoke;
}

#links ul {
    padding: 0px;
}

#links li {
    display:inline;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

#links li a:link {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: whitesmoke;
    text-decoration: none;
    /*Transitions*/ 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease; 
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease; 
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease; 
}

#links li a:visited {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: whitesmoke;
    text-decoration: none;
    /*Transitions*/ 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease; 
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease; 
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease; 
 }

#links li a:active {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: AliceBlue;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#links li a:hover {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: AliceBlue;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 6px;
    /*Glow*/ -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="links">
    <h3 id="subtitle">Links</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Resume</a></li> 
        <li><a href="">LinkedIn</a></li>
        <li><a href="">GitHub</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And codepen: http://codepen.io/abs26/pen/RNdbzj

Answer (score 1):

That happens because of font-weight:bold. The width of the font increases and there isn't a transition for that.

You could use text-shadow instead of font-weight to highlight the link when hovering it:

text-shadow: 0 0 1px AliceBlue, 0 0 1px AliceBlue;

```
#links li a:hover {
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
color: AliceBlue;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 6px;
**text-shadow: 0 0 1px AliceBlue, 0 0 1px AliceBlue;**
}
```

You could repeat the text-shadows to solidify the "border" as you see fit. For example: text-shadow: 0 0 1px AliceBlue, 0 0 1px AliceBlue, 0 0 1px AliceBlue;

Comment: Thanks for answering! I tried setting all the font-weights to normal first, to see if the stutter had been removed before I added in the new shadow effects, The stutter's still there though :/
Here is the updated codepen: http://codepen.io/abs26/pen/RNdbzj

Comment: Ah, sorry. I was using Firefox so I couldn't see that. 

Anyway, that is a webkit glitch. To go around it, you'll have to add display:inline-block to #links li a:link.

Also, font-weight:bold transitions properly on webkit.